# Declaring const enum to be used in different files with react-scripts-ts

Tags: typescript

We have two subprojects inside one project (backend and frontend), compiled independently (frontent is using `react-scripts-ts`). So, we can't have cross-imports between them, since this would break files structure in transpiled code. The structure if of the following kind:

```
/
|-client
| |-src
|   |-index.tsx
|   |-common.d.ts
|-src
  |-custom.d.ts
  |-app.ts
```

For now, the whole project is looking like this (intentionally simplified). Client side:

`common.d.ts`:

```
type UnionType = 'string1' | 'string2';
```

`index.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const enum Type {
    Type1 = 'Type1',
    Type2 = 'Type2'
}

interface Props {
    param1: Type;
    param2: UnionType;
}

class App extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        switch (this.props.param1) {
            case Type.Type1:
                return <div>{'Type 1 + ' + this.props.param2}</div>;
            case Type.Type2:
                return <div>{'Type 2 + ' + this.props.param2}</div>;
        }
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<App
    param1={Math.random() > 0.5 ? Type.Type1 : Type.Type2}
    param2="string1"
/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Server side:

`custom.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../client/src/common.d.ts" />
```

`app.ts`:

```
const enum Type {
    Type1 = 'Type1',
    Type2 = 'Type2'
}

const type: Type = Type.Type1;
const item: UnionType = "string1";
console.log(`Result is "${type}" + "${item}"`);
```

I'd like to move the `const enum Type` to `common.d.ts` to eliminate code duplication. But just declaring it as such and removing from both `index.tsx` and `app.ts` doesn't work:

```
declare const enum Type {
    Type1 = 'Type1',
    Type2 = 'Type2'
}
```

because, while backend inlines it properly, frontend compilation by `react-scripts-ts` preserves all usages such as `Type.Type1` as they are (checked using Chrome DevTools in loaded app), and code fails at runtime, since the corresponding object doesn't exist (and should not exist).

The repository with MCVE (after `enum` was moved) is [here](https://github.com/Cerberuser/const-enum-cross-import).

Is the desirable behaviour of referencing the same `const enum` from different places without importing it ever possible?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem based on the information you gave.  Can you verify that the file with the const enum is included in your frontend compilation by adding a syntax error and verifying that the error gets reported?

Comment: Added MCVE to see what's going on.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, btw, checked your suggestion - in fact, the syntax error in `common.d.ts` doesn't fail the compilation. That's strange, again, since types (and interfaces) are used as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is specific to `react-scripts-ts` using `ts-loader` in `transpileOnly` mode, which translates each source file independently (ignoring errors) and uses a separate pass on all files to report errors.  Thus, during translation of one file, references to const enums in other files will be unresolved and left as-is by default.  Other TypeScript features in which the emitted code depends on other files (such as namespace merging) won't work either.  So if you want to use this toolchain, you can't use such features.

Here is [a ts-loader issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/331) about the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep an eye on it, but for now such cross-usage seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

> ode fails at runtime, since the corresponding object doesn't exist (and should not exist).

Don't use a `const enum` between projects. You will always run into runtime issues.

Comment: Essentially, I'm asking could it be just inlined in all the scope where we use it, as it does when it is used in only one project. You state that this can't be done?

Comment: I can only be inline in *one* compilation. As soon as you have two projects it can't be inlined.

Comment: Then it's very strange that it gets inlined for *referencing* project (backend), but not for *containing* one (frontend).